# how to upgrade an existing column to a foreign key using sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have a oracle table `A` which contains a column `A.a` which used to store an attribute of the table. It is a big table with data. Now the semantic requirement of attribute `A.a` needs to develop into another table called B, B has an id column, and a column `B.a` which stores the same set of data as `A.a` (both columns are unique).

So now `A.a` should upgrade to a foreign key of the table `B`, then `A.a` should store `B.id` instead of VARCHAR2 and also the more tough part is I need to use `A.a` to find `B.id` via `B.a` and rewrite `A.a` with `B.id` because table A has existing data.

And I have to achieve this via SQL query.

So how to get this work? Apologize if I didn't make myself clear. Please feel free to leave any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've confused a few terms here, it seems. When you refer to a "schema" I think you mean "table". A query implies SQL, but queries alone do not enforce foreign key constraints. Also, PL/SQL is a procedural extension to SQL, I don't think it's relevant to this particular question.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp Thank you for the quick feedback. You are right I should say table or relation instead of schema, also use SQL query instead of PL/SQL. Thanks for the corection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the following schema:

```
tableA { a, x }
```

You want to transform it to the following schema:

```
tableB { id, a }
tableA { id, x } where id has a FK constraint to tableB (id)
```

You can do it with something like the following sequence of commands:

```
-- sequence to generate the tableB's surrogate key
CREATE SEQUENCE tableB_id_seq;

-- generate tableB
CREATE TABLE tableB AS
  SELECT tableB_id_seq.NEXTVAL AS id, a
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a
        FROM   tableA);

ALTER TABLE tableB MODIFY (id PRIMARY KEY);

-- add the FK column on tableA
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD (id NUMBER);

-- populate it
UPDATE tableA SET id = 
  (SELECT tableB.id
   FROM tableB
   WHERE tableB.a = tableA.a);

-- make it a FK
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD CONSTRAINT afk
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tableB (id);

-- drop the old column
ALTER TABLE tableA DROP COLUMN a;
```